# Форма с большим количеством полей или массово сохранить форму избежав кучи запросов?

Tags: php, foreach, form, mysql

Всем привет.

Возник вопрос сохранения формы, где куча полей. Оно то работает, но не уверен, что правильно делаю.

Например у нас форма

```
<form action="" method="post">

    <!-- ЭТО ВСЕ В ЦИКЛЕ -->
    <input name="1[firstname]" value="" />
    <input name="1[secondname]" value="" />
    <input name="1[nlastame]" value="" />
    <input name="1[phone]" value="" />
    <input name="1[address]" value="" />
    <!-- ЭТО ВСЕ В ЦИКЛЕ -->

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Где **1** - это id

Далее, я обрабатываю, скажем так

```
foreach ($_POST AS $id => $value)
{
    $id - ID записи, по которой я обновляю данные
    $value - содержит массив уже со значениями
    mysql_query(...запрос обновления...);
}
```

Что тут можно сделать, чтобы не делать запрос в цикле при обновлении и возможно ли такое вообще?

При этом получается, что нужно еще проверять некоторые поля на заполненность. Можно конечно валидацию замутить через js, но и в обработчике не мешало бы проверять поля какие нужно. тут не пойму как вывод ошибок сделать, если поле не заполнено, а остальные заполнены. Пробегать ДО сохранения и проверять на заполненность? Может кто подскажет каким образом это можно сделать?

Получается, что сколько будет итераций, столько будет и запросов, что имхо, получается накладно, если выставить по 30 на странице и в каждом по 10 полей.

То получается 30 запросов и 300 полей. Это если нужно обновлять в одной таблице.

Буду признателен за советы.

Comment: а зачем 300 полей? как то странно это.

Но если выбрать между одним большим запросом или сотней маленьких, то я бы выбрал первое. Нагрузка на сеть меньше и на сервер.

Comment: Валидации на стороне клиента недостаточно, клиент может просто отключить js или даже намеренно исказить данные в поисках уязвимости.

Comment: Это расширение не рекомендуется использовать при написании нового кода. Вместо него используйте mysqli или PDO_MySQL. Ознакомьтесь также с обзором MySQL API для более детальной информации по выбору MySQL API. http://www.php.net/manual/ru/intro.mysql.php

Comment: @KoVadim это массовое редактирование данных в таблице. Например таблица, где есть список пользователей. И чтобы постоянно не делать лишних телодвижений для открытия страниц редактирования, то решил попробовать массово. Ведь так удобнее и экономит время.

@VladD это админка. хотя я указал, что хочу не только на клиенте проверять.

@eicto что-то переделывать не вариант в этом направлении. пишу не новое, а пытаюсь улучшить управление тем, что уже есть.

Comment: @SilverIce вот это хорошая идея! Результат будет идентичным, еще и кнопку жать не нужно.

Сейчас попробую.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Массовое редактирование таблицы лучше сделать через ajax - обновлять в БД только то, что обновил пользователь... Ну и валидацию будет делать чуть-чуть удобнее. Если вам обязательно нужена запись именно при нажатии кнопки "записать" - то можно накапливать в сессии или в массиве на стороне клиента.

AJAX вряд ли уменьшит нагрузку на сервер. Но наглядность будет выше.